# How to access two dimmensional arrays in MASM

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, x86, masm

Can you show me how I can access two dimmensional arrays in MASM?

C++ code:

```
int k = 0
    for (i = 0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        if (k == text.length())break;
        for (j = 0; j<2; ++j)
        {
            for (t = 0; t<26; ++t)
            {
                if (text[k] == letters[t]){ tab[i][j] = t; k++; break; }
            }
        }
    }
```

MASM

```
mov al, [ebx]       ;ebx - begin of text array          
xor esi, esi        
for1:
cmp al, 00                  
je break_for1                   
mov j, 0        
for2:
mov t, 0                    
mov ecx, adrAlphabet        ;ecx - begin of letters array           
for3:               
;if (text[k] == letters[t]){ tab[i][j] = t; k++; break; }
mov ah, [ecx]               
cmp ah, 00                      
je end_of_alphabet              
cmp al, 00                      
je end_of_text                  
cmp al, ah                          
jne not_equal
;here comes the problem
        mov edx, t                      
        mov [letters + (esi*4 + j)*4], edx
;   
inc k                           
inc ebx                         
jmp break_t                 
; end if
not_equal:
inc ecx                         
inc t                       
cmp t, 26                       
jne for3

break_t:
inc j                           
cmp j, 2                    
jne for2

inc esi                             
cmp esi, 5                      
jne for1

break_for1:
end
```

That's only part of my code, but I just want understand arrays.
Can you give some example how I can use tab[i][j] in MASM?
Another question is, how I can modify the length of **tab** array? In short: at start of program the **tab** size will be calculated, then I want to set array size.

Thanks

Comment: 1) multiply `i` by the number of elements per row, add `j`, multiply the sum by the size of each element, and finally add the base address of the array. 2) Allocate memory for the array dynamically. How you do that depends on your target OS. If your writing a Windows application, look up `HeapAlloc`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A two dimensional array of size `[a][b]` is guaranteed by the C++ standard to be equivalent to a single one dimensional array of size `[a*b]`.
You can stop thinking of it as a two dimensional array and just think of it as a normal array, just a contiguous chunk of data.

That is, if you want to access `tab[i][j]` it's exactly the same as accessing `tab+a*i+j`

If you know that `a` (the number of rows in our array) is always 2, 4, or 8 you can directly use an expression of the form

`mov byte ptr [eax*8+ecx], someValue`

Where i is eax and j is ecx.

Otherwise you will have to compute `i*a+j` manually, using shifts or imul and use that as an index into your array.

For exemple:

```
; Write 0 at tab[i][j]
; We use EDX because of how IMUL works
mov edx, i ; EDX = i
imul a ; EDX = i*a
add edx, j ; EDX = i*a+j
add edx, offset tab ; EDX = tab[i*a+j] = tab+i*a+j
mov byte ptr [edx], 0
```

Comment: This answer contains several mistakes. From multiplying by number of rows, through wrong piece of assembly not calculating address correctly.