# How to access from memory matrices in MASM Assembly by using row/column index?

Tags: assembly, matrix, memory-address, masm32

How to access an element from matrix by using indexes like in C: `mat[i][j]`
I've tried this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27824989/5597102 but it gives me a big and unrelated number. In C is : `mat[i * nrCols + j]`

Code:

```
  mov EAX, 0 ; i = 0 -> EAX= 0
  mul w ; w = number of columns -> EAX= EAX* i
  add EAX, 1 ; j = 1 -> EAX= i * h + j
  add EAX, offset image -> EAX= image + i * h + j
  mov EAX, [EAX]
  push [EAX]
  push formatInt
  call printf
  add ESP, 8
```

Comment: `h = number of rows` => you want to multiply by number of columns. `push edx` puts address into stack, that's what you want to display with `printf`? To access element you would have to read the element from target adress, like `mov eax,[edx]` (or `push [edx]` to directly store it into stack). BTW, it's usually easier to get the idea what's going on by using debugger, than using debug logging with `printf`. That's like rescue mode, when for some reason debugger is not available at that spot of code.

Comment: I fixed, but for every values for 'i'and 'j' it gives me the first element of the matrix .@Ped7g

Comment: read `imul` specification. `imul w` will do `edx:eax = eax * w`. You didn't set `eax` to anything. Plus you use upper 32b of 64b result in `edx`. Wait, you have no idea what you wrote? That answer is wrong, the OP "got it working", probably fixing problems on his own. You need some x86 Assembly knowledge to resolve this (just use C++ instead, it will produce better code than you).

Comment: Changed the register to EAX and changed indexes by multiplying them by 4 and now it's working . There still is an 'Don't send' error the exit of the program . Thanks @Ped7g .

Comment: it was a DWORD array@Ped7g